# getResourceAsStream path related to project stucture?

Tags: java, inputstream

I know this should be simple, but surprisingly I can't google an answer.

I have this structure :

Myproj

|-src

|--com.mypackagename

|---MyClass.java

|-xml

|--book.xml

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(cl.getResourceAsStream("xml/book.xml"));
```

and it doesn't find my xml. Obviously, the path is wrong. Please, help me - how shall i set it right

Comment: Is the `xml` directory included within the Jar or class path?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that getResourceAsStream() will only load resources from the classpath. And as per given directory your xml file is not located on classpath. So, place your xml file under **WEB-INF/classes/book.xml** and access it as:

```
getResourceAsStream("book.xml")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be `../../book.xml` or `../../xml/book.xml` depending on how the  `xml` directory is included? And `\` is not a valid path separator for resource path look ups

Comment: But \ is not a valid path separator for resource paths and in fact, you can use `/` as a path separator in Windows without any issues...

Comment: Check what.....? I know for fact you can't use \ as a resource path look at and `/` doesn't need to be escaped...

Comment: so, maybe I should place my xml somewhere else?

Comment: @LyubovAlekseeva yes, place it under WEB-INF/classes/book.xml

Comment: so, in my project, in the root, I create folder WEB-INF, I make subfolder "classes" and place book.xml there? still got an error

Comment: @LyubovAlekseeva please post/update your project structure..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you `book.xml` file is kept in class path then you can simply access it by writing `cl.getResourceAsStream("book.xml")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `xml` directory is not within the classpath context of your application (ie embedded within the application Jar or with the classpath property), then you will need to reference the XML file as a `File`.  The path to which will be relative to the execution location of the program.

If the `xml` directory is within the classpath context (ie `classpath=.\xml;...`), then you will need to use a path something like `/book.xml`.

If the `xml` directory is relative to the classpath context (ie `classpath=.;...`), then you will need to use a path something like `/xm/book.xml`.

If the `xml` directory is embedded within the application context (packaged within the Jar), then you will need use either `/book.xml` or `/xml/book.xml` depending on how the directory is packaged